# Getting specific element(s) from after read from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

After I read from file:

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(","))     #split the file into multiple lists
```

How do I get some specific element(s) from those lists?

For example, only elements with index[0 to 3], but discard/ignore any elements after that.

Comment: Including the 3rd index or excluding?

Comment: including or excluding should be fine, it's just a small example.

Comment: Then check my answer below

Comment: What do you mean by "getting" those items? Do you mean printing them apart from the other items, saving them, processing them somehow, or other?

Comment: I want to print them apart from other items and return them back to use in other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the first three items in each line, you could use a list comprehension

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    firstitems = [line.rstrip().split(",")[0:3] for line in f]
```

Note that the `rstrip()` is needed to remove the final newline character, if there are fewer than four items in a line. Note that the "items" are all strings, even if they look like other types. If you want integers, for example, you will need to convert them to integers.

Then you can print them:

```
for line in firstitems:
    print(line)
```

Comment: tks, I will try them now

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    print('\n'.join([i for i in f.read().split(',')[0:3]]))
```

Comment: It only prints 3 lists instead of 3 elements from all list.

Comment: Tks a lot! I already closed the thread since @rory already gave me the answer. But I appreciate it nonetheless!